# initialize byte array field of struct while instantiating struct variable

Tags: rust

How to initialize a byte array field `[u8; 128]` of struct while instantiating the struct variable. This is my code

```
struct A {
    a: [u8; 128],
}

fn main() {
    let strr = String::from("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    let mut a_obj = A {
        a: [0u8; 128],
    };
    a_obj.a[..strr.len()].copy_from_slice(strr.as_bytes());
    
    println!("{:?}", a_obj.a);
}
```

I would like to initialize byte array field `a` of `struct A` from variable `strr` during the instantiation of `a_obj` variable.

Also I want to know how to get the size of byte array field `a` of `struct A`?

Comment: You seem to already do this fine, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance,

you can initialize an array with [std::array::from_fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html).

```
let a = A {
        a: std::array::from_fn(|i| {
            s.bytes().nth(i).unwrap_or_default()
        })
    };
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=904cfc09efb127002a66dadc38db73ae)

Please be aware that, the "size" of the array filed `a` (by definition of array) is fixed at compile time.

The memory layout of `a` field will be something like: `a: [65, 65, 65, ... 0, 0, 0...]`.

Comment: How to get the size of a struct array field?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the size of the array is fixed at compile time. This size is indicated in the array declaration (as part of the type). However, if you want to store the `len` as "the number of meaningful elements of the array", you should use an additional variable explicitly for that.